# Retrieve a value from a different class

Tags: python, oop, wxpython

I'm having troubles trying to retrieve a value in a drag and drop zone of my program.
I'm really sorry I'm new to Python and also in OOP so I'm sorry if my question is a bit dumb.

My objective is to retrieve the filename placed in the drag and drop zone after a click on the button (btn) from the DnDPanel class.
I tried many things but I still can't acces the 'filenames' value from the 'OnDropFiles' method, I created the 'buff_pdf' method to do so but it doesn't work.
I must be doing something wrong but I don't know what.
Thank you for your help !

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyFileDropTarget(wx.FileDropTarget):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, window):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.FileDropTarget.__init__(self)
        self.window = window
       
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnDropFiles(self, x, y, filenames):
        """
        Quand les fichiers sont glissés, écrit le chemin depuis lequel
        ils viennent
        """
        self.window.SetInsertionPointEnd()
        self.window.updateText("\n%d fichier reçu %d,%d:\n" %
                              (len(filenames), x, y))
        for filepath in filenames:
            self.window.updateText(filepath + '\n')

        return True
        
########################################################################
class DnDPanel(wx.Panel, MyFileDropTarget):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        file_drop_target = MyFileDropTarget(self)
        lbl = wx.StaticText(self, label="Put your PDF file in the drop zone :")
        self.fileTextCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self,
                                        style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.HSCROLL|wx.TE_READONLY)
        self.fileTextCtrl.SetDropTarget(file_drop_target)
        btn = wx.Button(self, label='buff files')
        #Retrieve filenames onclick
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.buff_pdf)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(lbl, 0, wx.ALL, 25)
        sizer.Add(self.fileTextCtrl, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

    def buff_pdf(self, event, MyFileDropTarget):
        """
        Retrieve filenames after clicking on the button (btn)
        """
        MyFileDropTarget.OnDropFiles(self)
        obj = MyFileDropTarget(self)
        obj.OnDropFiles(self)
        print(self.filenames)
        
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def SetInsertionPointEnd(self):
        """
        Put insertion point at end of text control to prevent overwriting
        """
        self.fileTextCtrl.SetInsertionPointEnd()
        
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def updateText(self, text):
        """
        Write text to the text control
        """
        self.fileTextCtrl.WriteText(text)

########################################################################
class DnDFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title="PDF Buffer")
        panel = DnDPanel(self)
        self.Show()

########################################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = DnDFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that `DnDPanel` is inheriting from `MyFileDropTarget` and also creating a child instance of `MyFileDropTarget`. It is better to just create the child instance and access that.

The `filenames` variable also needs to be defined as an attribute of the `MyFileDropTarget` class for access from the parent.

Here is the working code:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyFileDropTarget(wx.FileDropTarget):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, window):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.FileDropTarget.__init__(self)
        self.window = window
        self.filenames = []   # create attribute for later reference
       
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnDropFiles(self, x, y, filenames):
        """
        Quand les fichiers sont glissés, écrit le chemin depuis lequel
        ils viennent
        """
        self.window.SetInsertionPointEnd()
        self.window.updateText("\n%d fichier reçu %d,%d:\n" %
                              (len(filenames), x, y))
        for filepath in filenames:
            self.window.updateText(filepath + '\n')
        
        self.filenames.extend(filenames)   # update attribute

        return True
        
########################################################################
class DnDPanel(wx.Panel):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.file_drop_target = MyFileDropTarget(self)  # create child object
        lbl = wx.StaticText(self, label="Put your PDF file in the drop zone :")
        self.fileTextCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self,
                                        style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.HSCROLL|wx.TE_READONLY)
        self.fileTextCtrl.SetDropTarget(self.file_drop_target)
        btn = wx.Button(self, label='buff files')
        #Retrieve filenames onclick
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.buff_pdf)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(lbl, 0, wx.ALL, 25)
        sizer.Add(self.fileTextCtrl, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

    def buff_pdf(self, event):
        """
        Retrieve filenames after clicking on the button (btn)
        """
        # MyFileDropTarget.OnDropFiles(self)
        # obj = MyFileDropTarget(self)
        # obj.OnDropFiles(self)
        print(self.file_drop_target.filenames)  # from child object
        
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def SetInsertionPointEnd(self):
        """
        Put insertion point at end of text control to prevent overwriting
        """
        self.fileTextCtrl.SetInsertionPointEnd()
        
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def updateText(self, text):
        """
        Write text to the text control
        """
        self.fileTextCtrl.WriteText(text)

########################################################################
class DnDFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title="PDF Buffer")
        panel = DnDPanel(self)
        self.Show()

########################################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = DnDFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```